# Slow performance on MongoDB Full Text Search for 500,000 document collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo v3.4 DB on MLab's M2 instance with 3.5 GB RAM on a dedicated server.

I have 500,000 documents storing tweets with the body of the tweet in a single string field.  I have a $text index on that field.

When I query that field, it can take anywhere from a few seconds to over two minutes.  My query is:

```
[{
    "$match": {
        "$text": {
            "$search": "game losing"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$sort": {
        "score": {
            "$meta": "textScore"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$limit": 10
}]
```

I have reviewed the following posts:

- [Mongodb text search for large collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745908/mongodb-text-search-for-large-collection)
- [MongoDB Text Search on Large Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852368/mongodb-text-search-on-large-dataset)
- [Improving MongoDB Text Search Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514894/improving-mongodb-text-search-performance)

And have incorporated responses to them, but I still have very poor performance.

I do update the tweets consistently with any new stats (i.e. the like count of a tweet went up).

- Is Mongo text search just not designed for 500,000 + documents?
- This is just a pilot, and could grow to millions of tweets.  Should I just switch to ElasticSearch?
- Is there a different strategy I should be using?  Should I be storing stats data separately from the message document?

Comment: Can you post please `.explain` result: `db.collection.explain().aggregate(...)`

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is specially designed to process millions of documents. 500K is a very small dataset.

I think you are loading all the data (when a user searched for that item) simultaneously on the client-side, and Paginates it. It's causing server timeout. Because data also can be so huge.

What you can do here is: Use `Aggeration Framework`. Limit the no. of data to send from the Atlas server.

See the docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

See the `Examples` in that docs.       :)

Comment: I use MongoDB to process millions of documents specifically. The question was specific to $text.  Do you have experience with that?  I ended up using Atlas Search (Mongo) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @NickCaruso Yes, Atlas search is great. Use `$search` it retrives data in less than 50ms